# What is the difference between .clone and .backup commands in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

As far as I can tell both commands create a clone of the db in SQLite format in the end, so why are there two commands to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.backup` uses the [SQLite Backup API](https://sqlite.org/backup.html) to create a clone atomically, even if the database is in use.

`.clone` copies the database by just running SQL commands. As far as I can tell, no transactions are done on the source database when doing the clone, so it has a chance of getting partially updated data mid way through the clone.